# What is needed to make Terraform tolist() to work for my code after the replacement of list()

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is a simple question and I am trying to understand what documentation I can use to better understand this but this is what is happening. I'm looking to update my code of Terraform and I am running into an issue when it comes to using `tolist()`. My snippet of code:

```
subnet_ids = var.zone_awareness_enabled ? var.subnet_ids : tolist(var.subnet_ids[0])
```

When running my `terraform plan`, I get this error:

```
|     subnet_ids = var.zone_awareness_enabled ? var.subnet_ids : tolist(var.subnet_ids[0])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.subnet_ids[0] is "subnet-234324df3dfd"
│
│ Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert string to list of any single type.
```

When using `list()`, I had no problems but this is confusing since it is giving me the correct subnet but it's unable to process the request. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add the variable definition and value to the question. Also, do you want only one subnet from that variable or multiple?

Comment: Sorry, yes. It is only suppose to be 1 subnet with the `then` statement ":". However, your answer helped me get the subnet! Thanks you for helping @MarkoE. You were fast.

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot accept until 10 minutes have passed :)

Comment: Ah I was too fast then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the requirements it could only be a simple change to the code to look like the following:

```
subnet_ids = var.zone_awareness_enabled ? var.subnet_ids : [ var.subnet_ids[0] ]
```

On the other hand, if you take a look at the `tolist` [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/tolist), it says the following:

> Pass a **set value to tolist to convert it to a list**. Since set elements are not ordered, the resulting list will have an undefined order that will be consistent within a particular run of Terraform

So it is meant to convert a set (with no indices) to a list but it cannot convert a string to a list.